# Reuse an activity (create a new instance of)

Tags: android

How can a I reuse an Intent? I have a Class that I want to refuse (for drilling down a table layout).

```
Intent i = new Intent(AcmBrowseView.this, AcmBrowseView.class);
```

I've done a bit of searching, but no luck. How do I tell the compiler to create a new instance of AcmBrowseView.class?

Thanks,

Phil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set **android:launchMode="singleTask"** in your manifest for this activity. All intents will then be sent to the **onNewIntent()** event handler.

Comment: Your question confused me a little. If you do NOT want to reuse (i.e. create new instance) then use "standard" launch mode.

Comment: I get the following in log cat: 09-05 12:22:54.443: INFO/ActivityManager(61): Starting: Intent { cmp=com.acm/.views.AcmBrowseView } from pid 1730 - but the new instance never loads...

Comment: Ok, let me try to explain. I have a generic table layout in an activity (AcmBrowseView). The class loads the table from an xml file using a xpath expression. When the user clicks on a row, I generate a new path expression and want to create a new instance of AcmBrowseView. Thinking in OOP, I want to reuse the AcmBrowseView class and load it with new xml data.